# Default permission/group data in Django

Tags: django, database, permissions, usergroups, defaults

Every time I wipe the database of my Django app during testing (or when cloning or deployin), I have to go into /admin and set up permissions and groups.  Where would I put the code that would populate the DB with them and what would it look like?

Comment: You are creating database each time you make a change? I think that better solution would be to use `south` to migrate DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you can use fixtures.

For example:

```
python manage.py dumpdata auth > fixtures/auth.json
```

This will store all models of package 'auth' (Users, Groups Relations) into auth.json
After Deployment you can use the following command to load:

```
python manage.py loaddata auth fixtures/auth.json
```

This will restore your prev state of 'auth'.

Maybe it's good for you to switch to [South](http://south.aeracode.org/), a very famous part of Django to migrate databases instead of recreating them.

Comment: Thanks!  And you're right, I probably should just switch to the _right_ way of doing things... but sometimes the quick and dirty fix is just too easy to forego.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide fixtures with the initial required data and it will be automatically inserted when you `syncdb`. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/initial-data/)