# Normal user (not admin) registration and publishing in Wagtail

Tags: wagtail

I understand Wagtail is a CMS. Per my test so far, only the admin has permission to publish an article/content. I checked out "puput" and a few others as listed [here](https://github.com/springload/awesome-wagtail#bloggingnews). I wonder is there a way to allow normal user registration, login, publishing? Something similar to [Medium](https://medium.com/), where the normal user, or say the community, can contribute to the content generation.

I thought there might be a toggle or switch to enable this. But I didn't find it. I'm looking for a way that is either a package or a plugin or similar. Not coding from scratch. Ideally within Wagtail CMS, but other frameworks based on Django should also be fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wagtail provides two user groups:

- Editors: user within this group can create page and submit it to moderation
- Moderators: user within this group can publish pages that have been submitted to moderation.

To update groups for a given user, go the the django admin interface with admin credentails, usually the url is `your-domain/admin`

Then go to **Users** under **Authentication and Authorization** category

[image]

Then get into the user you want to allow posting pages,

Scroll down until **Permissions** category and moove groups Editors and Moderators from **Available groups** to **Chosen groups** as follow:

[image]

Then save new settings.

Comment: Thanks! Correct me if I'm wrong: the "users" in your answer still need to log in from "/admin". What I hope is something like "/account". So that the user can register by themself, and then they will have the right to publish articles after their registration. What makes it even better is: the admins (either Editor, or Moderators) should then have the right to delete an article if they find it inappropriate.

Comment: Hello @RodenLuo, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31335040/11905080) may be what you are looking for. Good luck